# Can Rspec wait for an answer from a ApplicationJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm calling a method inside a model, from a spec file. However, the method has a background job. How can I set spec to waiting for a response from the background job? Is it possible?

My Rspec File: user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { user.create(name: "Test User Name",last_name: "") }
  describe "existing user instance" do
    it "fetch last name" do
      user.update_last_name!
      expect(user.last_name).to eq("Test Last Name")
    end
  end
end
```

My Model File: user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def update_last_name!
    UpdateLastNameJob.perform_later(self.id,"Test Last Name")
  end

end
```

My Background Job Working in reddis: update_last_name_job.rb

```
class UpdateLastNameJob < ApplicationJob
  @queue = :default
  def perform(user_id,last_name)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @user.last_name = last_name
    @user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you updating last name in a job? Also, if you insist (or need to for some reason) to keep this technique, then you should probably test the two things separately. Test the job on its own, and test that the update method in the model calls the job.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bot more? I'm learning about Rspec, how can I set up the second option?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved in this way:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  let(:user) { user.create(name: "Test User Name",last_name: "") }


  describe "existing user instance" do
    it "fetch last name" do
      user.update_last_name!
      # update_last_name! is calling a background job, so the result will not be ready yet.
      expect(user.last_name).to eq("")
      # This line is goint to execute the backgound job
      perform_enqueued_jobs
      # Models reload with new data
      user.reload
      # Will work!
      expect(user.last_name).to eq("Test Last Name")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does it work if you're using sidekiq with ActiveJob as described here? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job

Answer (score 1):

If using Sidekiq, declare `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` in your test or in a `before` block.

Comment: please! Can you tell me what I have to do? I'm starting to learn.

Comment: Why do you assume Sidekiq is being used?

Comment: Ah, good point.  I thought I saw mention of Sidekiq, but it looks there was none.